# iPhone Gmail App won't stop sending notifications

Tags: iphone, applications, gmail, notifications

I tested out the Gmail App on my iPhone 4 (iOS 5.1.1) and have now stopped as it keeps asking me for my login details. I haven't deleted it.

It is continuing to send notifications even though I have switched them off for the app in the Notification Center Settings.

How can I stop the notifications?

I don't want to delete the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Notification settings aren't laid out very well. To fully disable notifications, you need to change pretty much all the settings on an app's notifications page in Settings.
Make sure you have turned *off* every switch circled here, and change **Alert Style** to *None*:

[image: Notification settings]

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had assumed that switching off Notification Center would disable everything. I had left Alert Style set to Banners.

Comment: What does the top on/off switch (notification center) do then?

Comment: The top switch, I believe, only determines whether the notifications that you receive *remain* in the notification center (the top-of-screen pulldown). It does not determine what happens *exactly when* the notification is received - this is determined by the 'Alert Style' section. I agree with @robmathers that it's a fairly confusing layout.